# code in subscribe method does not run in the right order

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

From get request I receive object array and I would like to assign that data to two different variables. One variable will get all the data, second variable  will get a mutated version of that data.

The code I tried:

```
this.service.getEmployeeTimesheets().subscribe(res => {

     this.timesheets = res; 
     this.mutatedTimesheets = res.map(j => {

       delete j["keyName1"];
       delete j["keyName2"]; 

     });
 console.log(this.mutatedTimesheets);

   });
```

What happens is that for some reason timesheets value  gets changed and mutatedTimesheets gets array of undefined

Comment: which version of angular?

Comment: My angular version is 6.1

Comment: I think you are using http. use httpclient https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: To make a multiple copies of the same object without having them modify each other you can use `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))`.

So in your case: `this.timesheets = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));`

There are more in depth explanation about how object cloning behaves in javascript (e.g: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)) but the JSON function chain does the trick here

---

In your `res.map()` you forgot to return `j`:

```
this.mutatedTimesheets = res.map(j => {

    delete j["keyName1"];
    delete j["keyName2"]; 
    return j;

});
```

Should do the trick

Comment: thanks, that fixed the undefined issue, but timesheets variable still is an array of objects with deleted properties. That is the most weird part for me. Map is supposed to give a new array while leaving the old one intact. However it also changes the original res array.

Comment: Right, that's because of how javascript makes a copy of the response object, to fix this you can do this ` this.timesheets = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));`

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work like that, when map function returns new array it returns new array, but object references are the same, for example if y have

```
    var user = {firstname:"user1",password:"pass123"};

    var first = [user];

    var second =[user];

    delete user["firstname"];

    console.log(first) // [{password:"pass123"}]
    console.log(second) // [{password:"pass123"}]
```

it means that user object references is same no metter in which array you set it,
so when you return new array using map, the object references stay same, so everything you do in objects are same for both arrays, you could do that to prevent that happening

```
this.mutatedTimesheets = res.map(j => {
    let newObjectReference ={...j};
    delete newObjectReference["keyName1"];
    delete newObjectReference["keyName2"]; 
    return newObjectReference;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing **2 mistakes**.

1) **Copying array by reference**. So timesheets also getting modified

2) **Not returning** the modified element from map

### Try this out

```
this.service.getEmployeeTimesheets().subscribe(res => {

     this.timesheets = res; 
     this.mutatedTimesheets = res.map(j => {

       // Re-reference the current object
       j = {...j};

       delete j["keyName1"];
       delete j["keyName2"]; 

       return j;

     });

     console.log(this.mutatedTimesheets);

   });
```